# viewing local video with colorbox iframe - black background and no resizing in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, colorbox

I'm trying to use [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) to show some videos within an html page, the html file and all resources, including the videos, will be on a USB drive and the user will open the html file. The idea is that when a link is pressed on the page, a colorbox will pop up and show just the video, with the background around the video being white. This works well in Firefox, it resizes the video to about 80% of the window's width and the background around is white, however in Chrome the video shows at the size of the original video file and the whole area that it's supposed to occupy after being resized is black (just the iframe got resized, but the video won't go bigger than the video file dimensions). I could live with this but I can't seem to get the black iframe background to match my white #cboxOverlay.

Using developer tools it seems like this is a problem with the user agent stylesheets, I see a few rules that could be causing the problem but somehow I'm not managing to override them with reset.css or regular css files:

```
video:-webkit-full-page-media {
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;}

body:-webkit-full-page-media {
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.